# Fixing corrupted jpgs that still looks ok visually

Tags: images, file-management, backup, image-processing

So like many people lots of my jpg photos had not been properly backed up with parity bits and all my backup copies had become corrupted due to "silent data corruption".

I scanned my drive using the software Bad Peggy as recommended by this post:
[Automating the scanning of graphics files for corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/276154/automating-the-scanning-of-graphics-files-for-corruption)

The software shows that 7k out of my 500k photos had been corrupted. Upon visual inspection, only around 200 photos had suffered from visual corruption. The vast majority had been corrupted in some other way (metadata, file format, etc) that doesn't affect the file visually. Nonetheless, this is annoying as I can't seem to publish any of these corrupted files with Lightroom or other software.

I'm wondering if there are any software solution to fix/strip/reformat these corrupt images so they are no longer flagged as corrupted?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late for the OP, but may provide useful information to others with the same problem. A jpeg file has a header section and a data sections. If the header is corrupt the file may not open at all. If only the data section is corrupt then some or even all of the image may display. If only the header is bad then it is possible to copy in a valid header (using a Hex editor) from another jpeg with the same size & resolution image. If only some of the metadata in the image section is bad it is possible to correct the values. There is a more detailed description of using a hex editor [here](https://www.disktuna.com/photos-on-sd-card-are-corrupt/).
 There are programs that can help do the file repair. You did not specify if you wanted a free or paid solution so I will provide both.

[File Repair](https://file-repair.en.softonic.com/) is fast and free; bare bones interface, only 2 buttons, Load and Repair; can only repair one file at a time; supports DOC, DOCX, DOCM, RTF, XLS, XLA, XLSX, ZIP, RAR, AVI, MP4, MOV, FLV, WMV, ASF, MPG, JPEG, GIFF, TIFF, BMP, PNG, RAW, PDF, MDB, MDE, ACCDB, ACCDE, PPT, PPS, PPTX, MP3, WAV.

[RS File Repair](https://rs-file-repair.jaleco.com/) is free and supports most image formats, but not gif or bmp.

[Jpeg Repair Toolkit](https://www.disktuna.com/jpgrepair-fix-and-repair-corrupt-jpeg-headers-and-invalid-markers/) is a paid program that can repair corrupt jpegs.

Comment: In the worst case, I have lost some images, but been able to rescue the thumbnail from the JPEG